# How to Sort the particular Files that begins with a string in a folder based on date and time in the filename in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm having files in a folder as below

1. text_20150625_142434.csv ( text_yymmdd_hhmmss)
2. text_20150626_184023.csv
3. text_20150623_174312.csv
4. temp_20150419_203908.csv

here i want to load the data from files that begin with "text" string and also i want to sort the files(only "text" starting files) based on the date and time in the file name after that i have to loop through the sorted files by for each loop container and  load each file data into the destination.

Actually for each loop container is not sorting the files  based on date and time, is there any way to sort the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with custom C# scripting.

Start by defining your own custom sort by creating a custom C# script component to list the files, sort them by your own method, and then load the sorted list into a collection data type or ADO record set (as a SSIS "object" type variable).

Then, you could use a ForEach ADO Enumerator or ForEach Variable Enumerator (similar to what is done [here](http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/05/28/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-result-set-enumerator/) and [here](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/18-Foreach-Loop-based-on-Variable-SSIS.html)) to iterate through each item in the collection, first setting your file name to the source in the string (or defining your connection to use a variable which the foreach loop updates each time through), processing it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your approach, i'm not familiar on writing the C# code to sort the files based on date and time in the file name.  Can anyone help me on this ?